# Enumerating the List of `nPr` (n Permute r) objects

Tags: algorithms, permutations

I have been using MATLAB for a particular project, and have seemed to find a function that may or may not exist. This question isn't MATLAB specific, more algorithm specific.

I have a list of 12 items, indexed from 1 to 12. I want to be able to create a list of all possible permutations of these 12 items where I only want to select 6 of them per entry.

[Here is a reference to what nPr is for those unfamiliar.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Permutation.html)

In MATLAB, there is a function called `perms(A)` such that it calculates `nPn` where `n = A.length`. However what I am looking for is `nPr` where `n = 12` and `r = 6`. Is there a way to either

1. Exploit the `perms` function such that it does `nPn` such that `n = 6`, but in a way that it actually calculates `nPr` where `n = 12` and `r = 6`.
2. Write a recursive algorithm to replace the `perms(A)` function and create a `perms(A,r)` function?

Any pointers or tips would be much appreciated and helpful.

Comment: Given the answer, it seems that the question should be migrated elsewhere.

Comment: I have been looking for nPr and found a good solution here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69507-npermutek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a MATLAB specific answer

> arrayfun(perms,nchoosek(A,r))

<sub>*Think of this as conceptual answer, because I have have been away from MATLAB and can't test it right now.</sub>

In other words,

1. get unordered combinations of elements in A, taken r at a time. using [nchoosek](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html).
2. get ordered combinations (with [perms](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)) of each unordered combinations. Applying a function to each element of a list can be done [via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983163/map-function-in-matlab) [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html;jsessionid=a08866e3b294432f6b5172a4c493).

Comment: previous answer I gave was actually giving unordered combinations (`nchoosek` itself). Sorry, I misunderstood the definition.

Comment: I could continue from that by defining yet again my own `perms(A)`, but I figured you won't really want that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudocode for the function Generate($k$, $A$), which generates all ordered $k$-tuples of distinct elements from the set $A$:

> Generate($k$, $A$)
>
> - If $k = 0$, output the empty tuple.
> - Otherwise, for each element $x \in A$ and for each $(k-1)$-tuple $\alpha$ in Generate($k-1$, $A \setminus \{x\}$), output $x,\alpha$.

More efficient algorithms exist, see Volume 4A of Knuth's Art of Computer Programming.

Comment: I had the same definition in mind and thought the computation and keeping track of $A \setminus \{x\}$ is inefficient. Is the algorithm in Knuth's have this inefficiency 'fixed', or is it another aspect?

Comment: Knuth's algorithm (not necessarily due to him) is probably more efficient, but unfortunately I don't have the book with me to check.